# "Открыто!" Какой это тип предложения?

Tags: синтаксис

Надпись на двери магазина "Открыто!" - это полное или неполное предложение? Или это особый тип предложения?

Comment: По какой причине восклицание? Наконец открыли, или редко бывает открытым?

Comment: @shampar На двери магазина? Тогда это призыв типа "Не проходите мимо!"

Comment: Призыв одним словом — не глаголом? Наречием?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “Открыто!” Какой это тип предложения?

**Безличное.**

Так такие предложения квалифицируются в известных мне источниках.

См., к примеру, [**Кустова Г.И. *Синтаксис современного русского языка***]:

> Краткое страдательное причастие в **безличных** предложениях стоит в
>   форме среднего рода ед. числа: ***Закрыто. Занято. Окрашено…***
>
> В АГ—80 такие слова, по форме и функции сходные с категорией
>   состояния, квалифицируются как причастные предикативы...

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего, это **ситуативно неполное предложение**.

В таких предложениях  недостающие члены подсказываются обстановкой, ситуацией, жестом. Они характерны скорее для разговорной речи. Например: Вы стоите на остановке, потом кричите: «Идет!» Присутствующим понятно, что идет какой-то транспорт. В предложении «Идет!» пропущено подлежащее. Или еще характерный пример. Вы встречаете подругу, вернувшуюся из отпуска:

-Ну как ?

-Отлично!

Здесь похожая ситуация. Написано "Открыто", а мы понимаем, что открыта именно дверь, а не что-то ещё.

Можно перепутать с безличным, но речь не о состоянии среды, как, например, холодно, а именно о двери, которую кто-то всё-таки открыл, действие происходит с помощью субъекта, неизвестного правда, но ведь не само собой.

Comment: Не дверь открыта, а магазин работает, это как бы его состояние, но можно ли считать безличным — не уверен.

Comment: Магазин работает - это не состояние среды магазина, это именно дверь открыта, сюда можно войти. Можно сказать "здесь открыто", а что открыто - сами догадываемся, что дверь, ведь не пространство в магазине...